# @ManyToOne mapping with only one field from the entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

[image: roomie_categories]

We have this `roomie_categories` table which has composite primary keys and is mapped in the application as follows:

```java
@Data
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CategoryCompositeKey {
  private UUID subcategoryId;
  private UUID categoryId;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "roomie_categories")
public class SubCategory {
  @EmbeddedId private CategoryCompositeKey compositeKey;

  @Column(name = "subcategory")
  private String subCategory;

  private String category;
  private String thumbnail;
}
```

[image: product_catalog]

I have this `product_catalog` table with two columns, `category_id` and `subcategory_id` which should reference the composite keys from the previous table. I didn't know how to map those so I did it this way:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "product_catalog")
public class Catalog {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
  private UUID id;

  private String description;
  private String blurb;
  private String type;
  private String surfaceType;

  @Embedded
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = SubCategory.class)
  @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "categoryId")
  @JoinColumn(name = "subcategory_id", referencedColumnName = "subcategoryId")
  private CategoryCompositeKey categoryCompositeKey;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "catalog", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<Selection> selections;
}
```

This worked and didn't throw any error on start-up but, as I was retrieving records, I got the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com...entities.CategoryCompositeKey field com...entities.Catalog.categoryCompositeKey to com...entities.SubCategory$HibernateProxy$uJfoGgxH

I tried adding a setter but that didn't work either:

```java
  public void setCategoryCompositeKey(SubCategory subCategory) {
    this.categoryCompositeKey = subCategory.getCompositeKey();
  }
```

How do I resolve this issue? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Category having multiple subcategories using UUIDs should look something more like:

```
@Entity
public class Category {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
  private UUID id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "catalog", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<SubCategory> subCategories;
  ..
}

@Entity
public class SubCategory {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
  private UUID id;//UUIDs are unique, so no need for a composite ID!
  
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
  private Category category;
  ..
}
```

I don't know why you have a roomie_categories with an ID, subcategory_id AND category_id UUIDs, but I suspect this isn't a Category->Subcategory relationship; Categories should have many subcategories, so cannot have only a single subcategory_id within the data.

Assuming that is what you really have; that a subcategory is assigned some 'other' category_id UUID that you need to have mapped as a separate FK within the category table with a subcategory_id value too, you might map it like this:

```
@Entity
public class SubCategory {
  @EmbeddedId 
  private CategoryCompositeKey compositeKey;
  ..
}

@Entity
public class Category {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
  private UUID id;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "catalog", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "category_id")
  @JoinColumn(name = "subcategory_id", referencedColumnName = "subcategory_id"
  private SubCategory subCategory;
  ..
}
```

If you just want access to the foreign key values in your entity, you might have confused @JoinColumn with @Override:

```
@Entity
public class Category {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
  private UUID id;

  @Embedded
  @AttributeOverrides({
  @AttributeOverride(name = "categoryId", column = @Column(name = "category_id")),
  @AttributeOverride(name = "subcategoryId", column = @Column(name = "subcategory_id"))
})
  private SubCategory subCategory;
  ..
}
```

Note though that you will have to maintain this yourself and ensure that Subcategory is persisted/merged first before Categories can reference that data: if there are foreign key constraints in the database, JPA knows nothing about this category->subcategory reference so cannot order it for you.